# How to add an element with a click event to an angular scope at runtime

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs

So far I've the following function called onGroundUserClick on the Scope passedScope.

I want to set it up so a function running when the iframe is loaded will set up ng-click.

```
var $tdName = $("<td/>", {
                    "class": "name",
                    "ng-click": "passedScope.onGroupUserClick(this)",
                });
```

When I open the developer console in Chrome I see the ng-click attribute was indeed added to the button but it does not fire up the event.

```
a class="link" ng-click="passedScope.onGroupUserClick(this)" href="">Account Manager a
```

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.. I'm kind of stuck here.

Comment: Because you never compiled new node, so Angular has no idea about ng-click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you have added the element to the DOM, call `$scope.$digest();` to prime the model and the UI to "sync up".  You can find a more thorough explanation here:

[$scope.$digest(); documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$digest)

Answer (score 0):

You can create view in `<td>` from loop like variable $tds and pass your logic in ng-click which will work.
You have to change the loop variable $tds value dynamically.

Like:

`<td ng-repeat="td in tds">
    <a ng-click="your_fun()">{{td.val}}</a>
</td>`

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to look like this:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.directive('custom', function ($compile) {
  return{
        restrict:'A',
        link: function (scope, ele, attrs) {
      scope.$watch(attrs.custom, function(html) {
        ele.html(html);
        $compile(ele.contents())(scope);
      });
    }
    
 };
});
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.html = '<button ng-click="doSomething()">Click me</button>';
$scope.doSomething = function(){
      alert('click');
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" >
<div custom="html"></div>
</div>
```